# Calculating the angle between 2 lines from their implicit equation

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces

My task was to find the point of intersection, which I did, but after that what are the steps to find the angle? I assume it is by using dot product and also calculating the length of both lines. I am not sure how to transform the information from an implicit equation to information I could input in the dot product.

Answer (score 1):

If the lines have equations $ax+by+c=0$, $a'x+b'y+c'=0$, their angle is the angle of their normal vectors, hence it is
$$\arccos\biggl(\frac{aa'+bb'}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sqrt{a'^2+b'^2}}\biggr).$$